# Silverlight access to other website Security Error

Tags: security, silverlight-5.0

I have a Silverlight 5 project that needs to load a text file from another website.  On the "other" website, I have installed a clientaccesspolicy.xml file that has

```
<access-policy>
    <cross-domain-access>
        <policy>
            <allow-from>
                <domain uri="*" />
            </allow-from>
            <grant_to>
                <resource path=/public_html/services/" include-subpaths="true"
            </grant-to>
        </policy>
    </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

This file is in the root directory of "other" web site, which is a Linux-based website.  (I also tried putting it in the public_html directory there.)

My code has this:

```
    var uri = "http://www.otherwebsite.com/services/TextFile.txt";
    var webClient = new WebClient( );
    webClient.OpenReadCompleted += ( s, e ) =>
        {
            using ( var stream = new StreamReader( e.Result ) )
            {
               // stream processing logic 
            }

        };
    webClient.OpenReadAsync( new Uri( uri, UriKind.Absolute ) );
```

I get a System.Security.SecurityException in the OpenReadCompleted delegate at the "new StreamReader" statement.

I can confirm that, if I explicitly navigate to the file in a browser, I can get to it.  I'm new to Silverlight and not a web guru, so there are probably a number of things I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you use fiddler to confirm that the SL app is reading the clientaccesspolicy?

Comment: I don't have fiddler, but using WireShark, I see a GET for clientaccesspolicy.xml, followed by a 200 OK, followed by the text of the xml file, followed by a GET for crossdomain.xml (which is not there), followed by a 404 Not Found.  So, I need one of these, too?

Comment: OK - having both files is apparently necessary.

Comment: No, only one is needed. If Silverlight tries to get the second one, it must mean it isn't valid, or doesn't contain rights that can apply.

Comment: Maybe you've got encoding errors, or something like that, and the file served isn't usable?

Comment: @jv42 - I suspect you might be right about why it needs the crossdomain.xml file.  Do you see anything in my clientaccesspolicy.xml that isn't valid?  The actual data file is fine; once I provided both "policy" xml files, it all worked perfectly.

Comment: I think your <resource> path is wrong. It should be "/services/" only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in jv42's comment above:  there was nothing wrong with the C# code, but the resource path value for the grant-to had the very specific path, /public_html/services/, but it only needed /services/, and the xml file itself had to be in the /public_html directory.